# Я могу использовать код из QtQuick в PyQT5 или Pyside2?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, pyside2, qtquick

Я хочу попробовать `использовать эффект` из этого кода

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height:600

    Image {
        id: image_bug

        anchors.fill: parent
        source: "images/Original_bug.png"
    }

    ShaderEffectSource {
        id: effectSource

        sourceItem: image_bug
        anchors.centerIn: image_bug
        width: 400
        height: 400
        sourceRect: Qt.rect(x,y, width, height)
    }

    FastBlur{
        id: blur
        anchors.fill: effectSource

        source: effectSource
        radius: 100
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В своем коде написаном на `Pyqt5` или `Pyside2`

```
import sys


from PyQt5.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint,
    QRect, QSize, QUrl, Qt)
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPropertyAnimation, QPoint

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsEffect

#Or

'''
from PySide2.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint,
    QRect, QSize, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
from PySide2 import QtGui
from PySide2 import QtCore
from PySide2.QtCore import QPropertyAnimation, QPoint

from PySide2.QtWidgets import QGraphicsEffect
'''



class test_mynu(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, arr="", parent=None):
        super(test_mynu, self).__init__(parent)
        self._expand = False                                # - self.__expand ; + self._expand  !!!
        #------menu_pos_block------
        self.menu_pos_block = QtWidgets.QWidget()

        blur = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect(blurRadius=5)
        self.menu_pos_block.setGraphicsEffect(blur)


        #------menu_pos_block_layout------
        self.menu_pos_block_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.menu_pos_block)
        self.menu_pos_block_layout.setObjectName(u"menu_pos_block_layout")
        #------menu_pos_label------
        self.menu_pos_label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.menu_pos_label.setText(arr)
        self.menu_pos_block_layout.addWidget(self.menu_pos_label)
        #------ADD------
        lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.menu_pos_block)



class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    # number of radio
    def num(self):
        return 3
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.toggle_animations = QtCore.QSequentialAnimationGroup(self)

        #------centralwidget------
        centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.setCentralWidget(centralwidget)
        #------layout------
        central_w_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(centralwidget)
        central_w_layout.setObjectName(u"central_w_layout")
        #------Spacer------
        vs_up = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(17, 105, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        central_w_layout.addItem(vs_up, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        hs_left = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(327, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        central_w_layout.addItem(hs_left, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        hs_right = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(326, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        central_w_layout.addItem(hs_right, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        vs_down = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 105, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        central_w_layout.addItem(vs_down, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        #------block------
        block = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        block.setObjectName(u"block")
        central_w_layout.addWidget(block, 1, 1, 1, 1)             ######
        #------layout------
        layout_block = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(block)
        layout_block.setObjectName(u"layout_block")
        #------menu_block------
        menu_block = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        menu_block.setObjectName(u"menu_block")
        layout_block.addWidget(menu_block)             ######
        #------menu_layout------
        menu_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(menu_block)
        menu_layout.setObjectName(u"menu_layout")

        self.menu_but = []
        self.menu_pos = []
        self.menu_by_pos = None

        for i in range(self.num()):
            menu_pos_block = test_mynu("menu_{}".format(i))
            menu_pos_block.setObjectName("menu_pos_{}".format(i))

            self.menu_pos.append(menu_pos_block)
            self.menu_pos[i].setGeometry(QRect(menu_pos_block.width(), menu_pos_block.height(), 151, 181))
            menu_layout.addWidget(self.menu_pos[i])

        #------menu_block_but------
        self.menu_block_but = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.menu_block_but.setObjectName(u"menu_block_but")
        menu_layout.addWidget(self.menu_block_but)             ######
        #------menu_block_but_layout------
        menu_block_but_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.menu_block_but)
        menu_block_but_layout.setObjectName(u"menu_block_but_layout")
        #------menu_but_radio------
        for i in range(self.num()):
            menu_but_radio = QtWidgets.QRadioButton('{}'.format(i))
            menu_but_radio.setObjectName("{}".format(i))
            menu_but_radio.toggled.connect(self.menu_animation)

            self.menu_but.append(menu_but_radio)
            menu_block_but_layout.addWidget(menu_but_radio)

        # Связывание меню к кнопкам и наоборот
        self.menu_by_but = dict()
        self.but_by_menu = dict()
        for i in range(self.num()):
            but = self.menu_but[i]
            menu = self.menu_pos[i]

            self.menu_by_but[menu] = but
            self.but_by_menu[but] = menu

        menu_block_content = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        menu_block_content.setObjectName(u"menu_block_content")
        menu_layout.addWidget(menu_block_content)             ######
        #------menu_content_layout------
        menu_content_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(menu_block_content)
        menu_content_layout.setObjectName(u"menu_content_layout")
        #------menu_label------
        menu_label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        menu_label.setText('text, text text, text')
        menu_content_layout.addWidget(menu_label)

        self.num = 0
        self.menu_pos_ter = []

    def menu_animation(self):
        self.num =self.num+1
        self.toggle_animations.clear()

        num = int(self.sender().objectName())
        self.menu_pos_ter.append(self.menu_pos[num])

        # Хитрая сортировка, что сначала вернет элемент с _expand = True
        for menu in sorted(self.menu_pos_ter, key=lambda x: x._expand):
            pos1 = QPoint(self.menu_block_but.x() - menu.width(), menu.y())
            pos2 = QPoint(self.menu_block_but.x() +self.menu_block_but.width(), menu.y())

            but = self.menu_by_but[menu]
            menu.raise_()
            self.menu_block_but.raise_()
            if but.isChecked():

                start_pos = pos1
                end_pos = pos2
            else:
                start_pos = menu.pos()
                end_pos = pos1

            anim = QPropertyAnimation(menu, b"pos")
            anim.setDuration(1000)
            anim.setStartValue(start_pos)
            anim.setEndValue(end_pos)

            self.toggle_animations.addAnimation(anim)


        if (self.num == 1) or (self.num == 3):
            self.toggle_animations.start()
            self.menu_pos_ter.clear()

        if self.num == 3 :
            self.num = 1
        print("--x--")


StyleSheet = """
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget{
background:#000;
color:#fff;
}
#centralwidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget{
background:#fff;
color:#000;
}
#click_me{
background:#000;
color:#fff;
}
"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(640, 570) #Size window
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Могу ли я как то совместить** или хотя бы перевести **qtQuick на PyQT5** или PySide2

Я не совсем понимаю как и где работает `qtQuick` Но судя по этому [туториалу](https://wiki.qt.io/PySide_QML_Tutorial_Basic_1) qtQuick  может работать с PySide но я не знаю нужно ли мне его скачивать отдельно или он уже у меня установлен с PySide2.

Comment: **1)** QtQuick не зависит от библиотеки, поэтому будет работать даже на оригинальной Qt -- на с++, поэтому нет разницы PyQt5 или PySide2 **2)** pyqt5 и pyside5 оба с Qt5 работают и названия их классов одинаковое, поэтому можно через try/except делать импорт обеих библиотек разом, пример: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/6e7148fc5ea37513749cd4376d08c1a3022efa0d/Base64_examples/gui_base64.py#L10

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/326268/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine


class GUI_MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, widget, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setWindowTitle('GUI_MainWindow')
        self.resize(600, 600)
        self.widget = widget

        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(centralWidget)
        layout.addWidget(QLabel("<h1>Hello World !</h1>", alignment=Qt.AlignCenter))
        layout.addWidget(self.widget, stretch=1)        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    myApp = QApplication(sys.argv)

    url = QUrl.fromLocalFile("qml_window.qml")
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    context = engine.rootContext()
    context.setContextProperty("main", engine)
    engine.load(url)

    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)

    widget = QWidget.createWindowContainer(engine.rootObjects()[0])

    window = GUI_MainWindow(widget)
    window.show()

    sys.exit(myApp.exec_())
```

---

**qml_window.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    property var theme: String("#ffffff")
    property var focusColor: String('transparent')
    id: applicationWindow
    visible: false                                     // Важно
    width: 600
    height:600

    Image {
        id: image_bug
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: "im.png"                               // im.png установите свое
    }

    ShaderEffectSource {
        id: effectSource
        sourceItem: image_bug
        anchors.centerIn: image_bug
        width: 300                                     // 400
        height: 300                                    // 400
        sourceRect: Qt.rect(x,y, width, height)
    }

    FastBlur{
        id: blur
        anchors.fill: effectSource
        source: effectSource
        radius: 100
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Попробуйте добавить :

```
import os 
...
DIR_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
...
    file = os.path.join(DIR_PATH, "qml_window.qml")
    ...
    url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(file)
...
```

---

```
import sys
import os                                                            # +++
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

DIR_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))                # +++


class GUI_MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, widget, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setWindowTitle('GUI_MainWindow')
        self.resize(600, 600)
        self.widget = widget

        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(centralWidget)
        layout.addWidget(QLabel("<h1>Hello World !</h1>", alignment=Qt.AlignCenter))
        layout.addWidget(self.widget, stretch=1)        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    myApp = QApplication(sys.argv)

    file = os.path.join(DIR_PATH, "qml_window.qml")                     # +++
    url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(file)                                     # +++

    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    context = engine.rootContext()
    context.setContextProperty("main", engine)
    engine.load(url)

    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)

    widget = QWidget.createWindowContainer(engine.rootObjects()[0])

    window = GUI_MainWindow(widget)
    window.show()

    sys.exit(myApp.exec_())
```

Comment: Вы не знаете почему деректория файла у меня qml такая страная у меня? `C:\Users\user>python C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\widgets\7\test.py
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
file:///C:/Users/user/qml_window.qml: No such file or directory` Я бы хотел что бы файл находился рядом с test.py

Comment: @orlatym я не понимаю вас, у меня все файлы `.py`, .`qml` и изображение лежат в одном каталоге.

Comment: А у меня `QUrl.fromLocalFile()` и `setSource(QUrl())` выводят `C:/Users/user/` возможно это иза того что я запускаю код test.py  из командной строки. но по идеи такого быть не должно

Comment: @orlatym я предложил некоторые дополнения, смотрите дополнение в ответе.

Comment: @orlatym  я просто набираю в командной строке  `D:\_Qt\__Qt>python qml-window-1.py` .  `D:\_Qt\__Qt` - каталог где лежат все файлы.